# Alinear span y textbox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente formulario para realizar login pero no se alinean.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No consigo que el span de usuario y el de password estén en la misma línea, es decir, que no haya un salto entre el `span` y el `input`.

Estoy usando bootstrap 4.

```css
/* LOGIN */
.login {
background: #D8D8D8;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 25px;
margin-top: 25px;
display: inline-block;
}

.btn-acceder {
margin-top: 15px;
}

.icon-left {
float: left;
margin-top: 2.5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.form-right {
float: right;
}

.checkbox-align {
text-align: right;
color: red;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="login">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Inicio Sesion</h2>
    <div class="col-lg-10" role="form">
        <span class="fa fa-user icon-left col-lg-2 control-label"></span>
        <input type="text" id="userlogin" name="userlogin" class="form-control form-right" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="col-lg-10" role="form">
        <span class="fa fa-unlock-alt icon-left col-lg-2 control-label" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="password" id="passlogin" name="passlogin" class="form-control form-right" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><br>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Recordarme
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Acceder</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

He intentado mediante `float` que el span y el `input` esten a izquierda y derecha pero no consigo que se alineen y por último con `display: inline-block;`

Y lo otro es que no consigo que la caja del login se ponga en el centro, he probado con `center-block` pero tampoco se va al centro.

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tienes los `span` fuera de los `divs`, tan solo muevelos dentro, tambien puedes aplicar `margins` a la clase `.icon-left` para ajustarlos. Te dejo un ejemplo con el codigo que has pasado:

```css
/* LOGIN */
.login {
background: #D8D8D8;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 25px;
margin-top: 25px;
display: inline-block;
}
.btn-acceder {
margin-top: 15px;
}
.col-lg-10{
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}
.fa{
  width: auto !important;
}
.icon-left {
margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-right {
float: right;
}
.form-control{
  width: auto !important;
}
.checkbox-align {
text-align: right;
color: red;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
<div class="login">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Inicio Sesion</h2>
    <div class="col-lg-10" role="form">
        <span class="fa fa-user icon-left col-lg-2 control-label"></span>
        <input type="text" id="userlogin" name="userlogin" class="form-control form-right" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-lg-10" role="form"><br>
        <span class="fa fa-unlock-alt icon-left col-lg-2 control-label" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="password" id="passlogin" name="passlogin" class="form-control form-right" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><br>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Recordarme
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Acceder</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estoy usando tu solución pero por extraño que parezca no me está dando resultado y te aseguro que está tal cual lo has puesto tu. Lo peor es que en el snippet tuyo veo que funciona.

Comment: Fijate que he añadido un par de `<br>`, luego puedes aplicar margenes a los div segun necesites.

Comment: Sí, me había fijado y lo tengo tal cual lo has puesto tu.

Comment: Intenta recrear un snippet con el codigo que estes usando, incluyendo el framework de bootstrap. Es posible que el css de Bootstrap te este cambiando alguna cosa.

Comment: Asegurate tambien de colocar primero las etiquetas css de Bootstrap y luego la tuya con tu css.

Comment: Añadido el snippet

Comment: @David Echale un vistazo a los cambios que he hecho.

Comment: Sigue sin ir, de hecho si te fijas y abres tu snippet a pantalla completa se ve  sin alinear, solo se alinea cuando se hace responsive.

Comment: Actualizado de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias SilverSurfer, ya están alineados. Veo que para conseguirlo has tenido que usar !important en el css para forzar la posición de fa, ¿es correcto?

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear en boostrap existe la clase de [form-group](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) para alinear los elementos contenidos.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="uLogin" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uLogin" placeholder="Login">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Ejemplo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/progressive-button-on-login)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes el contenido **oficial** que brinda Bootstrap acerca de los forms:

[Forms - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

La explicación a tu problema y solución esta en:

> Horizontal form

Entra en el [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/), y apreta **CTRL + F** y coloca **"horizontal form"**

*Estoy seguro de que encontraras la solución a tu pregunta.*